# Free CVS repository?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I’m looking for a free CVS repository to access via Eclipse and for minimum two users to submit, update and commit changes.

I’ve been scouring the net but with no luck.

Does anyone know of such a service?

Sincere
- Mestika

Comment: In this day and age, there is no possible justification whatsoever to use CVS for a new project. You don't have to hop on the DVCS bandwagon, but please at least use Subversion...

Comment: Commercial or open source code?

Answer (score 2):

try http://unfuddle.com/ There were some limitations for number of users (up to 2 if I remember well) if a project was not an open one.

all the options are right there: http://unfuddle.com/about/tour/plans

Answer (score 0):

SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/

Comment: Discountinued in 2017.

Answer (score -1):

I was quite happy using CVS on [BerliOS](http://developer.berlios.de/). A feature I liked particularly are the [CVS snapshots](http://developer.berlios.de/docman/display_doc.php?docid=33&group_id=2).

Answer (score -3):

Tortoise SVN is a freeware. You can try that.

Comment: Tortoise SVN is a great SVN client for Windows, but the guy is looking for a hosting server.  I recommend http://unfuddle.com as well. it's excellent, though it doesn't do CVS, only SVN.